# Проверка одинаковости символов в строках С++

Tags: c++

Условия задачи: создать программу, какая проверят являются ли заданные строки "родственниками". Родственниками считать слова, для записи которых используются одинаковые символы. Примером таких строк есть "баран" и "барабан". Т.к. это олимпиадная задача, то важно время исполнения и вес.
По каким-то причинам, если в слове есть повторяющиеся символы, на вывод идёт not parents. Кто-то может объяснить почему так происходит и посоветовать решения для оптимизации?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s1;
    string s2;
    getline(cin, s1);
    getline(cin, s2);
    bool isEqual[s2.length()];
    bool answ = true;
    for (int i=0;i<s1.length();i++){
        for (int y=0;y<s2.length();y++){
            if(s2[y] == s1[i]){
                isEqual[y]=true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i < s2.length();i++){
        if (isEqual[i] == false){
            cout << "not parents";
            return 0;
        }
    }
    cout << "parents";
}
```

Comment: Осталось понять ваше задание и по какому параметру оптимизировать, а заодно и ваши способы оценки этого параметра и почему значения параметра вас не устраивают.

Comment: по этому коду  "баран" и "барабан" не подходят

Comment: решил сначала использовать английские символы, и только потом подключать возможность обработки кириллицы

Answer (score 1):

Ну, это ж не Unicode :), я бы сделал два массивчика из 256 элементов `bool`, и просто, проходя по словам, менял бы соответствующий элемент на `true`. Очень быстрая операция. А потом просто проходил бы по массивам и смотрел на соответствие значений элементов - нулевые или нет.

Если нужно только **полное соответствие** - т.е. буквы одного и второго должны совпадать - типа "баран" и "барабан", но не "баран" и "баранка" - то можно просто сравнивать два контейнера.

что-то типа

```
vector<bool> v1(256,false), v2(256,false);
for(auto c: s1) v1[c] = true;    
for(auto c: s2) v2[c] = true;
if (v1 == v2) ...
```

Вот рабочий код: https://ideone.com/kY8W3n
Или, если вектора смущают - так: https://ideone.com/z6cqOX

Comment: Не уверен что это решит проблему, т.к. необходимо проверять совпадении символов как таковых, а не соответствие двух строк. Возможно я чего-то не понял. Заранее извиняюсь, являюсь абсолютным новичком в с++ :)

Comment: А я и проверяю не совпадение строк, а совпадение наличия одинаковых символов в строках.

Comment: Пока что не умею пользоваться векторами, потому не до конца осознаю написанный код

Comment: @Harry ох не нравится мне `vector<bool>`. Лучше уже обычный `char c1[256]`)

Comment: @pavel Тогда так: https://ideone.com/z6cqOX

Comment: Гляньте на код без вектора, с массивом. Ссылка в ответе. Только сравнивать тогда приходится с помощью `memcmp`, чтоб не писать еще один цикл :)

Comment: а то я asm код глянул, испугался... Массив компактнее генерирует)

Comment: @Harry Дичайше извиняюсь, но я практически не понимаю этот код. За мои 30 минут разбора я так и не продвинулся в направлении понимания. Не могли бы вы описать всю логику происходящего пошагово?

Comment: Нет, еще подробнее разжевать не могу.